# Stuck using the linear optimisation function to optimise portfolio weights

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-sheets, solver, quantitative-finance

**Context**

I am currently seeking to build an optimisation function to build portfolio weights. Its akin to the excel solver or the google sheets solver function (albeit faulty). Though how it works differs to the excel VBA. Its the first time I am playing with it. Below is the script:

```
function PortfolioOptimisation() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var assets = ['AssetOne','AssetTwo','AssetThree','AssetFour','AssetFive',
                  'AssetSix','AssetSeven','AssetEight']; //What I using to optimise variables
    var weights = ss.getRangeByName(assets); 
    // The variables to optimise
    var factors = ['OptimisationExpectedReturn','OptimisationExpectedVol','OptimisationNegativeReturn',
                   'OptimisationPositiveReturns','OptimisationPositiveRisk','OptimisationNegativeRisk',
                   'OptimisationSortinoRatio','OptimisationSharpeRatio']; //Store it in a variable as I do not want to keep typing up the named ranges. 
    var sumWeights = ss.getRangeByName('OptimisationWeightsSum')
    var optimalPortfolios = ss.getRangeByName(factors);


    // Call the optimiser engine
    var engine = LinearOptimizationService.createEngine();
    engine.addVariable(optimalPortfolios[0]);// Add first variable,
    // Add constraints: weights =1, Sum of weights =1, weights = greater than 0, less than or equal to 1.
    var constraint = engine.addConstraints([0.0],[1.0],[weights,sumWeights],[weights]);
```

This is what I am trying to apply it to:
[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GVvLCi_surJdxmi3R-I6MvwsD-3Dy2F4gPIKS3lU0Fc/edit?usp=sharing)

It contains the formulas in each cell that will be calculated using the optimisation function.

**Problem**

How do I execute the optimisation function to find the optimal values based on the 'portfolio section/column' in the spreadsheet? How could I improve my code above?

In the spreadsheet, in the second tab/sheet, on the first Portfolio name, for example, I want to optimise the weights of the assets by maximising the Sortino ratio and minimising it. So using the optimisation engine, what would be the best weights of the assets that could help me achieve this? I want to do the same thing for the other listed portfolios in the portfolio column.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about your current issue and goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about them, can I ask you about the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: Thank you for responding. No problem, it was my fault. I assumed. I have updated the google sheet with examples. basically, I want to calculate the weights by optimising for the values on the far right (E[r], E[v]...). The portfolio names on the left highlight which variable will be optimised (so what combination of weights of each asset will achieve the highest of the Sortino ratio on the right hand side of the table for example). Plugging in the weights automatically updates the other figures. If you want, I can open the spreadsheet for you to play around with and get a feel for it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying and updated sample Spreadsheet, I cannot still understand about your goal. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: No problem, thank you! I have updated the problem but will keep updating as I also learn more :)

Comment: You are using an LP solver, but risk is often modeled using quadratic terms. You would need a QP solver for that.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Where can I find this in the google documentation? This was the only solver I could find.

Comment: I don't think they have a QP solver. Sorry.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen No problem, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Simpler solution:

```
# Portfolio returns calculated
def portfolio_returns(weights, returns):
    """weights -> returns"""
    
    # take the weights, transpose it and take the matrix multiplication
    return weights.T @ returns

# Volatility
def portfolio_volatility(weights, covmat):
    """Weights -> Covariance"""
    
    # Weights transposes, matrix multiply with covmatrix and matrix multiply this with weights and square root the answer
    return (weights.T @ covmat @ weights)**0.5

# minimum vol for a certain return
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def minimize_vol (target_return, er, Cov):
    
    # number of assets
    n = er.shape[0]
    # guess weights to achieve goal
    initial_guess = np.repeat(1/n, n)
    # make copies of this boundary for every asset
    boundary = ((0.0, 1.0),)*n
    # Return should be whatever the target is
    return_is_target = {
        'type': 'eq',
        'args': (er,),
        'fun': lambda weights, er: target_return - portfolio_returns(weights, er)
        
    }
    # weights should equal one
    weights_sum_1 = {
        'type':'eq',
        'fun': lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1
    }
    # Optimiser
    results = minimize(portfolio_volatility, initial_guess,
                       args=(cov,), method='SLSQP',
                       options={'disp': False},
                       constraints=(return_is_target, weights_sum_1),
                       bounds=boundary)
    return results.x

# Target weights
def optimal_weights(n_points, er, cov):
    """ Get a list of weights for min and max returns"""
    # generate the target return give the min and max returns
    target_rtns = np.linspace(er.min(), er.max(), n_points)
    # for target rtns, loop through the function for what this would be and give me a set of weights
    weights = [minimize_vol(target_return, er, cov) for target_return in target_rtns]
    return weights

# multi asset portfolio for mimimum volatility portfolio
def plot_Portfolio(n_points, er, cov):
    """
    plot Efficient portfolio for n assets
    """
    weights = optimal_weights(n_points, er, cov)
    Returns = [portfolio_returns(w,er) for w in weights]
    Covariance = [portfolio_volatility(w,cov) for w in weights]
    Portfolio_final = pd.DataFrame({"Returns":Returns, "Volatility": Covariance})
    return Portfolio_final.plot.line(x="Volatility", y="Returns");
```

--> Derived from Edhec course

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/optimization/linear-optimization-solution) to find the optimal values you should run `engine.solve()`. This will return the values, thus you will want to store them in a variable to then use them wherever you want.

```
...
var constraint = engine.addConstraints([0.0],[1.0],[weights,sumWeights],[weights]);

// Get the result of the optimization engine
var solution = engine.solve()
```

Also please bare in mind that [solve()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/optimization/linear-optimization-engine#solve) has a default deadline of 30 seconds. If you want to modify the default deadline time simply pass the amount of seconds you want as a paramater like this `engine.solve(300)`. Also, check [these methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/optimization/linear-optimization-solution#methods) that can be applied to your solution to, for instance, determine if it is either feasable or optimal.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think I may have errors in my code. I just tried running it and I had an error for `engine.addvariable`. The issue is I don't quite know how to organise it to take parts of the spreadsheet and calculate it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So what do you want your variables to be ? The simplest form of [addVariable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/optimization/linear-optimization-engine#addvariablename,-lowerbound,-upperbound) will take a name and an upper and lower bound. How many variables do you want, what would their names be and what would their upper and lower bounds be? Thanks !

Comment: Not to worry. Not sure how to do it on Google sheets. Found a way to do it in Python. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi ! For documentation purposes for other users could you please share how you achieved this in Python ? Thanks !

Comment: Its quite a long code but I will do so later this week, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A python solution

```
def ticker_list():
    tckr_list = ['AVV.L', 'SCT.L', 'ROR.L', 'OCDO.L', 'CCC.L', '3IN.L', 'AVST.L', 'ASC.L', 'SPX.L','ECM.L', 'TRN.L', 'PLTR']
    return tckr_list

def Optimize_MaxR_Vc():
    # after getting a list of your asset returns...
    
    # Number of assets in the portfolio
    tckr_list = ticker_list() # this should be for the number of assets you have. if saved as a
    Assets = tckr_list
    num_assets = len(Assets)

    # Lists of variables for Portfolio creation
    Portfolio_returns = []
    Portfolio_Volatilities = []
    Portfolio_GrossR = []
    Aveva_Returns_weight = []
    Softcat_Returns_weight = []
    Rotork_Returns_weight = []
    Ocado_Returns_weight = []
    Computacenter_Returns_weight = [] 
    TInfrastructure_Returns_weight = []
    Avast_Returns_weight = []
    ASOS_Returns_weight = []
    Spirax_Returns_weight = []
    Electrocomponents_Returns_weight = [] 
    Trainline_Returns_weight = []
    Palantir_Returns_weight = []

    #Optimising for expected returns and standard deviation
    Gross_rtn = Gross_return()

    for x in range (100000):
        weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        Portfolio_returns.append(np.sum(weights * Portfolio_rtns.mean() * 250)) # expected returns
        Portfolio_Volatilities.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(Portfolio_rtns.cov() * 250, weights)))) # standard deviation 
        Portfolio_GrossR.append(np.sum(weights * Gross_rtn.mean() * 250)) # Gross returns
        Aveva_Returns_weight.append(weights[0])
        Softcat_Returns_weight.append(weights[1])  
        Rotork_Returns_weight.append(weights[2]) 
        Ocado_Returns_weight .append(weights[3]) 
        Computacenter_Returns_weight.append(weights[4]) 
        TInfrastructure_Returns_weight.append(weights[5])
        Avast_Returns_weight.append(weights[6])  
        ASOS_Returns_weight.append(weights[7])
        Spirax_Returns_weight.append(weights[8])
        Electrocomponents_Returns_weight.append(weights[9])
        Trainline_Returns_weight.append(weights[10])
        Palantir_Returns_weight.append(weights[11])

        # Create an array of data for portfolio
    Portfolio_returns = np.array(Portfolio_returns)
    Portfolio_Volatilities = np.array(Portfolio_Volatilities)
    Portfolio_GrossR = np.array(Portfolio_GrossR)
    Aveva_Returns_Weight = np.array(Aveva_Returns_weight)
    Softcat_Returns_Weight = np.array(Softcat_Returns_weight)
    Rotork_Returns_Weight = np.array(Rotork_Returns_weight)
    Ocado_Returns_Weight = np.array(Ocado_Returns_weight)
    Computacenter_Returns_Weight = np.array(Computacenter_Returns_weight)
    TInfrastructure_Returns_Weight = np.array(TInfrastructure_Returns_weight)
    Avast_Returns_Weight = np.array(Avast_Returns_weight)
    ASOS_Returns_Weight = np.array(ASOS_Returns_weight)
    Spirax_Returns_Weight = np.array(Spirax_Returns_weight)
    Electrocomponents_Returns_Weight = np.array(Electrocomponents_Returns_weight)
    Trainline_Returns_Weight = np.array(Trainline_Returns_weight)
    Palantir_Returns_Weight = np.array(Palantir_Returns_weight)


    #Creating a table
    Portfolios = pd.DataFrame({'Return': Portfolio_returns, 
                           'Volatility': Portfolio_Volatilities,
                           'Gross Return': Portfolio_GrossR,
                           'Aveva Weight': Aveva_Returns_weight,
                           'Softcat Weight': Softcat_Returns_weight, 
                           'Rotork Weight': Rotork_Returns_weight,
                            'Ocado Weight': Ocado_Returns_weight,  
                            'Computacenter Weight': Computacenter_Returns_weight,
                            '3Infrastructure Weight': TInfrastructure_Returns_weight,
                            'Avast Weight': Avast_Returns_weight,
                            'ASOS Weight': ASOS_Returns_weight,
                            'Spirax Weight': Spirax_Returns_weight,
                            'Electrocomponents': Electrocomponents_Returns_weight,
                            'Trainline': Trainline_Returns_weight,
                            'Palantir': Palantir_Returns_weight})


        # Custom Portfolios

# With this range, what different types of portfolios can we build? 
    # if volatitlity is within this range, where is volatility when you search for max return?
    Min_return = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.135) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=14.358)].min()['Return']
    Return = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return)]
    Min_return_1 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.200) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=9.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_2 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_1)]
    Min_return_2 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.300) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=8.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_3 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_2)]
    Min_return_3 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.400) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=7.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_4 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_3)]
    Min_return_4 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.500) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=6.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_5 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_4)]
    Min_return_5 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.600) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=5.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_6 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_5)]
    Min_return_6 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.700) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=4.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_7 = Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_6)]
    Min_return_7 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.800) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=3.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_8= Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_7)]
    Min_return_8 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.900) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=2.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_8= Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_8)]
    Min_return_9 = Portfolios[(Portfolios['Volatility']>=.100) & (Portfolios['Volatility']<=1.00)].min()['Return']
    Return_9= Portfolios.iloc[np.where(Portfolios['Return']==Min_return_9)]
    
    Final_MaxOp = pd.concat([Return,Return_2, Return_3, Return_4, Return_5, Return_6,
                        Return_7, Return_8, Return_9])

    return Final_MaxOp
```

I saved it as a module in python lab so that to run it, all I needed to do was:

```
Portfolio = P.Optimize_MaxR_Vc() # load the results

Portfolio # show the results
```

P is the module I saved it under so I imported it as
`from Portfolio import P`

Before coming up with the ranges, run:

```
  # What is the max returns? 
   max(Portfolio_returns)
    
  #What is the min volatility?
   min(Portfolio_Volatilities)
```

You can separate the various parts of this code into different functions and run them to test out different ranges.